# What is the replacement for the Web Intents HTML standard?

Tags: html5, standards

"Web Intents" were deprecated in Chrome 24 (November/2011) and are no longer supported in any browser:

> We also gathered a lot of valuable data and feedback from our experimental support for [Web Intents](http://webintents.org/) and decided to [disable the feature](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/a-web-developers-guide-to-latest-chrome.html) in today's Beta release.

Is there an HTML5 standard that I can look into as an alternative to what Web Intents intended? I'm interested in how web services can be stitched together. For example, imagine a website that can import a image from any number of web-services, modify the image in some way, then push the file back to any number of other web-services, all via HTML5 standards.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than waiting for another stack to be developed, you might be interested in the commentary [here](http://benlog.com/2012/02/09/a-simpler-webbier-approach-to-web-intents-or-activities/).  It's not super recent commentary, but seems to offer reasonable suggestions.  In a nutshell, there are a couple minimalist alternatives mentioned which work with JS shims:

1. Using custom protocol handlers as the target of postMessage channels.
2. Using message channels via navigator.registerContentHandler and navigator.registerProtocolHandler

Answer (score 0):

On 23/May/14 Robin Berjon created a interesting unofficial draft proposal of "Web Wishes": http://darobin.github.io/web-wish/